# I want to scrape all members details from table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.gmcgujarat.org/searchdoctor.aspx'
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

name = soup.find(" ")
for count in range(3333,4444):
        data = {name: " "}
        r = requests.post(url, data=data)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    
        table = soup.find('table',{"id":"divtest"})
        for tr in table.find_all('tr',class_='odd')[1:5]:
            print tr.text
```

The code is not giving 'tr'and 'td' data,since 'tr'is given in odd and even form i don't know how to scrape data from that.

Comment: If you want to scrap the data so why are your using 'request.post' instead you should use 'request.get'

Comment: i tried but its not working..@Mr. Stark

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get all `td` value in this website is

```
data = {name: " "}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table',{"id":"divtest"})
tr_arr = []
for tr in table.find_all('tr'):
  tr_arr.append([td.string for td in tr.find_all('td')])
```

As you need to further dig into the `tr` to find all `td`s.

---

But let's say, you just care about `class='odd'`, then adding `class_='odd'` in `find_all` is already the correct way.

However, what if some of the rows(`tr`) contains data you don't want. Let's say you only want to get all row with `class='odd'` or `class='even'`, but some rows come with `class='na'`.

Actually, you can pass dict to class identifier in `find_all` like this:

```
table.find_all('tr', {"class": ["odd", "even"]})
```

Or even more adding your specific logic by

```
table.find_all('tr', class_= lamdba x: x is not None and x in ['odd','even'])
```

Comment: i am not getting it,can u help me with the code?@MatrixTai

Comment: @ghate, it is similar to the code you wrote, I just change the last part for finding `td`. I add some part of your code for clarifying.

Comment: @ghate, Are you sure you can get targeted html text by `r = requests.post(url, data=data)`?